# how to list all the PID's associated with certain application?

Tags: sockets

While reading about `unix socket programming`, I got a statement `A socket is one end of an inter-process communication channel` now I am just curious to know that -Is there any way to list all the `PID's` or `threads` more specifically ,associated with certain application.
for an eg. lets say for `chromium` .So that by looking at the `port numbers` associated with that `PID's` ,I could verify that indeed Socket is a `inter - process communication` channel or `inter-application level` channel.

I looked at [threads associated with processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/892/is-there-a-way-to-see-details-of-all-the-threads-that-a-process-has-in-linux) , but I think its different from what I was thinking of.

One more thing,,how can we list all `PID's` associated with any `port number`??

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856590/determine-the-process-pid-listening-on-a-certain-port

Comment: @KasiyA I have already seen that link ,, but my question is bit different,, related to certain application(like chromium).

Comment: also did you read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14082119/4023950? it's the same as accepted answer here!

Comment: @KasiyA because it was related to my last question(how can we list all PID's associated with any port number??)..

Comment: @jazzz both questions are generic enough to belog on [unix.se]. Please ask further questions there, unless there is something Ubuntu-specific about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`lsof`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lsof):

```
$ lsof -i:80 -t
1229
18521
```

Comment: Thanx @Andy ,well it is showing --enable-pinch PID for chromium ,and I have multiple tabs opened ,(I think PID's associated with multiple tabs should also be there as they too are using port no. 80 or 443)..

Comment: Use pgrep -P $chromiun-PID . This will get you all the child processes. As well, ps --ppid $chromium-PID will work.